# VBA to Find and Remove

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have been trying for 5 hours looking at various tutorials but cant find exactly what I need.

I have a 50000 rows and 1200 columns sheet which I am trying to clean up.

I simply need to Keep the Column Names (header names) and delete the Column Names from all the other cells in that column if they are there - and put the output into a new sheet i.e. sheet 2

Please note
I dont want to use formula just VBA

I cannot use any references to character for example remove all before:  because other values inside a cell might also have :

here is a mockup
[image: mockup]

Comment: Loop over the data in row 1, then call `Range.Replace` on the rest of each column using the value in row 1 and replacing with `vbNullString`.

Comment: Keywords: 2d array, instr, replace. Read data into array  -> check if values starting from row 2+ contain value from row 1 in respective columns -> do the replace (or mid w/e you prefer). And finally, output that array into new sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I should have mentioned I am new to VBA and so far only managed to follow tutorials and example VBA code - and then modify to work in my sheet when possible - I am not at this moment able to create any code myself I dont really have understanding of the syntax or logic or form the code - I have managed to make changes where possible and adapt. if anyone has any tutorial or link or can add VBA here I will try it thanks

Comment: You say: *I am not at this moment able to create any code myself ...*. So, instead of starting to learn, and get help with the parts you don't know, you ask other people to do your complete work for you.

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg for your kind information different people learn differently I have used excel with functions until now when I could not get the results I needed – I’ve read various tutorials and spent a lot of frustrating hours and days before posting here for help. Because I could not find an example of what I needed to do. After first 2 replies I asked someone can provide link to post or tutorial as you can see.

Comment: I made a request for help and some kind members posted and helped out because I needed to do this now and they did not see anything wrong in replying with actual answers so what is your problem? If people with similar problem to mine will see this in the future it will help them and not create a post as I would not have if I could have found myself. what you want me to do go and learn then post here after a month. You have not contributed to this post and banned my account. If there are other moderators I want them to review Tom Brunberg comment and behaviour.

Comment: He has also removed another comment by another moderator who was more helpful in request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove Column Titles From Column Data

- It is assumed that the data (table) starts in cell `A1` in worksheet `Sheet1` of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).
- This is mostly useful for a one-time operation because it will only copy values. It will not copy formulas and formats.
- Adjust the worksheet (tab) names.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveTitles()

    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Data
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cTitle As String
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        cTitle = CStr(Data(1, c))
        For r = 2 To rCount
            Data(r, c) = Trim(Replace(Data(r, c), cTitle, vbNullString))
        Next r
    Next c
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If dws Is Nothing Then
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=sws)
        dws.Name = dName
    Else
        dws.UsedRange.Clear
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = Data

End Sub
```

Comment: wow thank you VBasic2008 Nicely explained with comments I have tried it in mockup and it's working will update after I check in main file - very kind of you thank you

Comment: Thank you again this worked great in main file too